# Custom watchface not showing up in Android Wear app

Tags: android, wear-os

So I'm giving a try in developping a custom watchface, and so far I've only managed to get it working on the emulator provided by android studio.

I would like to get my custom watchface to be listed among other watchfaces in the Android Wear companion app on my phone, however I can't manage to get it in the list of available watchfaces.

What I did so far :

- Make a stand alone wear app with a watchface service
- Try it into the emulator (launched the wear module directly into the wear emulator, working so far)
- Make a mobile app with no activity
- Add the wearable module into the mobile app gradle file
- Export the APK for the mobile module
- Installed it onto my phone

Any help would be very much appreciated, this is driving me insane !

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Azsde.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For people who have the same problem, make sure the permission are set in BOTH mobile and wear module. This was my problem, it is now fixed.

Comment: I have the same problem, I can install the watch face if i directly run it on my wear emulator, but I can't install it through my mobile app. This didn't work for me though. My understanding is the phone is supposed to push the wear apk to the wear once connected right? However nothing is happening!

Answer (score 3):

**short answer:** You must build a release apk, and not the debug apk.

**long answer:** When you build the debug apk, the wear app does not get embedded in the mobile apk. However, when you build the release apk, you'll see that the wear apk gets embedded in the mobile apk in the res/raw folder (if you open the mobile apk in winrar). After this just open up the watch emulator and sync the apps and it should appear!

credits: schoolsteps.in